# Launch App1 from App2,then press home button to the home screen,and open App1 again by press icon,why onCreate get called?

Tags: android, launchmode

I launched App1 from App2, and here are the methods in App2:

```
Intent resolveIntent = getPackageManager()
    .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.weijunhao.launchmode");
startActivity(resolveIntent);
```

Then I press the home button to go to the home screen and I open App2 by pressing the launch icon.

Why does the `onCreate` method get called and not the `onRestart` method?

Comment: post your manifest (for both apps) please

Answer (score 1):

When an `Activity` is no longer visible (like when you press the home button) it goes to the stopped state. From that state it may need to go through the `onCreate()` method if the system has killed the process to release memory for apps in the foreground (or system processes, I suppose).

There's a nice life-cycle diagram in [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#alc).

[image]